# Windows Event KeyPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard

I would like to know if it is possible to activate an event with keyboard arrows, directly on the page, without having to have the mouse in an input or something like this, I tried this and it did not work.

```
keyPress (e){
 if(e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
   console.log(e.key)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. But when you call it, it is not on `keyPress` instead on `keyDown`.

You can add an `eventListener` to listen to `keypress` in `componentDidMount`.

```js
  componentDidMount(){
   window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyPress);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
   window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyPress);
  }
  keyPress (e){
   if(e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
     console.log(e.key)
   }
  }
```

Comment: No, I can not be in an entry or something like that, a screen has to be totally clean and as soon as I hit an arrow and I run, I know it's an event window but I do not know how it works